# Kafka unable to resolve javax/xml/bind/* ClassNotFoundExeption for java 12?

Tags: java, java-8, apache-kafka, java-12

I'm learning kafka and  just downloaded kafka 0.10.1 (as it's the requirement of my project) and whenever i run this command line code

`bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties`

i get this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.urlSafeBase64EncodeNoPadding(CoreUtils.scala:298)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.generateUuidAsBase64(CoreUtils.scala:286)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer$$anonfun$getOrGenerateClusterId$1.apply(KafkaServer.scala:336)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer$$anonfun$getOrGenerateClusterId$1.apply(KafkaServer.scala:336)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.getOrGenerateClusterId(KafkaServer.scala:336)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:203)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:39)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:67)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 10 more
```

I'm actually using java 12 and `javax/xml/bind/*` is removed from java 11 so some suggestion were to add the dependencies in the pom.xml file but i unzipped kafka from a .tar file and not build it using maven so how can i resolve this error in kafka??

should i download java-8 for this??

Comment: Did you fix the issue? If yes, please share the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm learning kafka and just downloaded kafka 0.10.1

This version of Kafka does not support versions of Java above 8.

Only the newest Kafka 2.2.0 (which very likely will work the same for your learning purposes), added support for Java 11

Answer (score 0):

This `javax/xml/bind` API is removed since Java 11. You can refer to [How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j) for a workaround

Comment: i downloaded java 8 and i'm using that.

Comment: @Hummingbird Were you able to resolve NoClassDefFoundError ?

Comment: @Hummingbird If the answer was helpful could you please mark the answer as useful. Thank you

Comment: i'm ready to mark it as useful but i don't know how to do it, also i'm not marking as accepted as it din't solve my answer.

Comment: @Hummingbird It's ok. Cool

Comment: @Humming The linked solution works for any Java at or above version 11.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu yes, but the solution assumes it was build from maven but i do not have pom.xml to add the dependency's.

Comment: @humming You can download the referenced libraries through maven central and use the jars directly.

Comment: how can i add jar files to shell files??

Comment: @humming you need to put them onto the classpath when invoking your java application, irrespective if you start it directly or through a shell file

Answer (score 0):

I am  using JDK10. for that I  have added something like below to make it work for me.
1) edit  kafka-run-class.bat
2) the set COMMAND=%JAVA%  **–add-modules java.xml.bind** rest of the lines remain same.
3) Run kafka server